# MVC patterns with WPF + NHibernate + IoC

Tags: wpf, nhibernate, model-view-controller, principles

I'm looking for patterns and principles for using with WPF and NHibernate in model-view-controller style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a pretty good sample application plus write-up for using WPF and NHibernate together.  The article is sufficiently long without also delving into MVC & IOC.  It covers the hardest bit, which is managing NHibernate sessions in long lived contexts.

[Building a Desktop To-Do Application with NHibernate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Paul Stovell's [Magellan](http://www.paulstovell.com/magellan) MVC container - I don't think it tries to be an ORM, so you'd need to hook NHibernate up, yourself...